# How to manipulate the values of Hashtable for just specific key in powershell?

Tags: hashtable, powershell-4.0

I might need a second set of ideas here.

This is what 'd to achieve: 
I need to perform a task in a Hashtable (Powershell) to each value of a particular Key

I am scripting a portion of enabling a dfsr replication and I am stuck because
the follow command  needs to be executed:

New-DfsReplicationGroup -GroupName "" | New-DfsReplicatedFolder -FolderName "" | Add-DfsrMember -ComputerName Server1,Server2

If I run the command it self on a powershell terminal works without any problem.

On a Hashtable I already have the follow:

Content of Grouping  servers list
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Group Name1         {Server1, Server2}
Group Name2         {Server6, Server9}

Which now has to be easier right?
Thinking as Array:

```
Write-Verbose "Configuring a full-DFSr connection "
       for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $server_list.Count ; $i++) 
       {
           for ($j = $i + 1 ; $j -lt $server_list.Count ; $j++) 
            { 
              Write-Verbose ("Adding bidirectional connections between the member computers named {0} and {1}" -f $server_list[$i],$server_list[$j])
                 $dfs_connection_status = Add-DfsrConnection -GroupName $GroupName -SourceComputerName $server_list[$i] -DestinationComputerName $server_list[$j]
                  Write-Output $dfs_connection_status
            } 

       }
```

However I can't figure it out how to manipulate the content once the key is found

Then I took a break from that script portion and decided to break it down a simple a+b

Take a look on the follow:

where $($key.Name) has 
the key value:d and the Value content is:1,4,5

lines as follow

```
$num = @{a= "Test"
         b= "Test2"
         c= "Test3"
         }

$num.d = @() #adds to an array
$num.d+= '1'
$num.d+= '4'
$num.d+= '5'

$result= $num[0]+$num[1] or if decided $result= $num[0]+$num[2]
```

result should be '5' or  '6' if (1+5)

```
 $num.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Value | Where-Object {$_.Key}
```

Name                           Value
----                           -----
d                              {1, 4, 5}
a                              Test
b                              Test2
c                              Test3

```
   #$sum+= $num.ContainsKey("d")+$num.ContainsKey("d")+1
   $num.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Value | Where-Object {$_.Key} 
      if ($num.ContainsKey("d")) { $num['d'] }
```

if the d key is found then manipulate the value content as needed . Thinking on my original script for dfsr would be once the group name is found enable the bidirectional replication Server1  -> Server2  and Server2 -> Server1

I could not make it to work so I decided to create a new array (probably is not really needed) what I was thinking okay so you found the d key now lets move all the content to a new array so we can manipulate it.

$vm_list+= $num.Values | Where-Object {$num.ContainsKey("d")} | % ToString

Write-Host "`n`n`t VM_list:`t" $($vm_list)

Hope you guys can help

## Any idea would it be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So  I found the answer , can't believe it was that easy maybe was loosing my mind.

I am sharing a possible solution to the community ;)

"there is always a multiple ways to get to a place so this could 
be one;)"

```
  $script:vmlist = @{}     #Hashtable
    $vm_list = @()           #Array

    $vmlist.d = @()
    $vmlist.d+= 'Server1'    
    $vmlist.d+= 'Server2'


    if ($vmlist.ContainsKey("d"))  #Looking for a particular Key
{ 
$vmlist['d']    
    $vm_list+= $vmlist['d']
    Write-Host "`n`n`t VM_list:`t`t $($vm_list)`n`n$($vm_list[0])`n$($vm_list[1])`n$($vm_list[2])"
    Test-Connection $vm_list[0+1]
}
     else {Write-Host "Value not found"}
```

Printing the content of Hashtable

```
VM_list:  Server1 Server2
```

Printing the content of the new Array , noted that it will contain the values from the Key d

```
VM_list[0]:Server1
VM_list[1]:Server2
```

result:

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address     Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------     -----    -------- 
Server source  Server2      10.114.x.y                          32       0
Server source  Server2      10.114.x.y                          32       0
Server source  Server2      10.114.x.y                          32       0
Server source  Server2      10.114.x.y                          32       0

Hope you guys can use it

Regards
JCayetano